# How to find out which row was clicked using React JS map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to identify which row was clicked using React JS map function? I have a list where data coming from API. Now I have a delete and edit button with each row. but unable to find on which row I was clicked? How to do this?

Demo:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/map-delete-edit-jeuyfz?file=/src/App.js

My Code:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button} from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const data =[
  {
      "title": "title1",
      "IsActive": 1
  },
  {
      "title": "title2",
      "IsActive": 0
  },
  {
      "title": "title3",
      "IsActive": 1
  },
  {
      "title": "title4",
      "IsActive": 1
  }
]

export default function App() {
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(data);
  
  const deleteHandle = (i) =>{
    console.log(i);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {data2
          ? data2.map((val, i) => (
            <div className="box" key={i}>
              <h2>{val.title}</h2>
              <Button onClick={deleteHandle}>Delete</Button>
              <Button>Edit</Button>
              </div>
            ))
          : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank You for your efforts!

Comment: pass the `title` or `index` or w/e as `<Button onClick={()=>deleteHandle(val.title, i)}>Delete</Button>`

Comment: but how to use `val.title` in click function?

Comment: it's just another argument ... `const deleteHandle = (arg1, arg2 .... ) =>{ ... }` where they are passed as `<Button onClick={()=>deleteHandle(arg1, arg2, ....)}>Delete</Button>` you can pass event as  `<Button onClick={(e)=>deleteHandle(e, arg1, arg2, ....)}>Delete</Button>`

Comment: KcH not getting title can you give answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the index and the `val` from the map function, you can pass it to the `deleteHandler` like so:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(data);
  
  const deleteHandle = (i) =>{
    console.log(i);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {data2
          ? data2.map((val, i) => (
            <div className="box" key={i}>
              <h2>{val.title}</h2>
              <Button onClick={() => deleteHandle(i)}>Delete</Button>
              <Button>Edit</Button>
              </div>
            ))
          : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will allow you to access those and figure out which one was clicked

Comment: can we pass title here with id ?

Comment: you can pass the title with `val.title` instead of i to `deleteHandle`, so instead of `deleteHandle(i)`, it's `deleteHandle(val.title)`. If you want both then `deleteHandle(i, val.title)` and modify `deleteHandle` to accept two parameters and use it

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleteHandler` is missing some contextual information, which is actually available since you are interacting through the array with `.map()`.

To identify which row is clicked on, simply pass an argument to the handler instead, i.e.

```
<Button onClick={() => deleteHandler(i)}>Delete</Button>
```

...where `i` is simply the index of the row you've clicked on.

To remove the element from your data, you can use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) where you simply copy the pre-existing data, splice out the entry by the received index `i`, and then return the mutated array:

```
const deleteHandler = (i) => {
  setData2(data => {
    const newData = [...data];
    newData.splice(i, 1);
    return newData;
  });
};
```

See a proof-of-concept of your forked CodeSandbox example here:

[image: Edit map delete/edit (forked)]

Comment: How can I get the title when I clicked on delete button?

Comment: @RohitVerma You can pass additional arguments to the function